# "Axis -1 does not exist for dimension 0" error when using numpy vectorize

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to map a custom function to each element of a numpy array. The function in question:

```
def find_closest(value, lookup_array, breed=True):
    if breed == True:
        return lookup_array[sum(lookup_array <= value) - 1]
    else:
        return lookup_array[sum(lookup_array >= value) - 1]
```

This function is essentially a version of excel match but it is used to find the closest value from a range for given input either from above or from below. The lookup_array will be sorted accordingly before being passed to this function.

When I tried to map this function over an array, I got an error. For example:

```
import numpy as np
mapped_arr = np.vectorize(find_closest)(np.random.normal(size=(10,10)),np.array(np.arange(-20,20.25,0.25)))
```

I got an error:

> Axis -1 does not exist for dimension 0.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `np.vectorize` passes scalars of all arguments to you function.  It'll be simpler if you just iterate on the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to tell the program it is not allowed to vectorize over the lookup array. You can fix that easily by using the parameter excluded. This code worked fine for me (note that the parameters now have to be named):

```
import numpy as np

def find_closest(value, lookup_array, breed=True):
    if breed == True:
        return lookup_array[sum(lookup_array <= value) - 1]
    else:
        return lookup_array[sum(lookup_array >= value) - 1]
        
lut = np.array(np.arange(-20,20.25,0.25))
sample1 = np.random.normal(size=(10,10))

func = np.vectorize(find_closest, excluded=['lookup_array'])
print(func(value=sample1,lookup_array=lut))
```

Comment: I tried this solution. However I got another error : "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'". I think either the function is not applied at an element level or the excluded= parameter is not taken into account.